# Turn off the prompt asking "You usually dismiss these notifications. Keep showing them?"

Tags: notifications, settings, 9.0-pie, google-pixel

I often dismiss notifications from my home screen by swiping them. For example, I collaborate through google docs a lot, and get updates on when a document has changed. I like knowing when this happens, but often don't need to see the change itself so I just dismiss the notification by swiping. However, almost every batch of notifications I do this with, I get prompted with:

"You usually dismiss these notifications. Keep showing them?"

It interrupts me being able to dismiss notifications. And I get asked this constantly even after selecting "Keep showing".

**How can I prevent these "You usually dismiss these notifications. Keep showing them?" notifications from appearing?**